# WebFront for sharing diskspace

Tags: backup, web, webserver, frontend

I just set up an Ubuntu server with 4 TB of Raid 5 space and a public IP, and I would like to share it with my family and friends.

Is there any easy Web Frontend, with authentication and quotas, to allow my users to use the space via a simple web interface?

Comment: Please do not cross-post questions on multiple SE sites in the future. Choose which site it is most appropriate for and ask it there. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you looked at [OWL](http://owl.anytimecomm.com/)?  As with any of this kind of thing, you'll want to so some testing and possibly hardening, since you'll be publishing this online directly.

EDIT: Open source options:

- [HFS](http://www.rejetto.com/hfs/)
- [PHPfileNavigator](http://pfn.sourceforge.net/)
- [Gallery Server Pro](http://www.galleryserverpro.com/features.aspx)
- [Mollify](http://code.google.com/p/mollify/)

Comment: Edited to add some open source alternatives

Answer (score 1):

Does it have to be a web gui interface?  If not, then webdav (described as "web folders" in windows) may be the best option as your server appears as a normal folder in explorer.

To add the folder, it is as easy as going to Computer, right-click in empty space, New Network Location and going through the wizard.

On your side, [this](http://www.howtoforge.com/how-to-set-up-webdav-with-apache2-on-ubuntu-8.10) should help get webdav up and running.